# Marquee not working in spinner Android

Tags: android, spinner

In my app I have tried to use marquee functionality but its not working. I used it in a Spinner and I have also seen many examples that its working in it but In my case its not working. In XML page under `Spinner` tag I used,

```
android:ellipsize="marquee" 
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
```

And In java page I have used this,

```
private void setStateListener(){
     final Spinner  s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerState);


         s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
             public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,  int position, long id) {

                 s.setSelected(true); 
                //some code...
                        ...
                 }
              }
             public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
             }
         });

 }
```

Spinner don't have any problem its showing result but marquee not working on it.

Where I am wrong?

Plese help.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one..
Put this line of code in your text view....

```
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:duplicateParentState="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="@string/your_text">
<requestFocus
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

Comment: I know it for text view. I want to do it for `Spinner`.